# Python: File IO - Disable incremental flush

Tags: python, file-io

Kind of the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608316/is-there-commit-analog-in-python-for-writing-into-a-file).

Is there a way to tell Python "Do not write to disk until I tell you to." (by closing or flushing the file)?  I'm writing to a file on the network, and would rather write the entire file at once.

In the meantime, I'm writing to a StringIO buffer, and then writing that to the disk at the end.

Comment: Why?  What possible value is there in waiting to become I/O bound when you're done computing?

Comment: The server is set up to commit the file-cache before it is closed, and it is slowing everything down. While this prevents data-loss, the file I'm writing is useless unless it is complete. Writing the file to disk at once has tested to be much faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a glance at the python manual does not indicate an option to set the buffer size to infinity.

Your current solution is basically the same concept.

You **could** use Alex's idea, but I would hazard against it for the following reasons:

1. The buffer size on open is limited to 2^31-1 or 2 gigs. Any larger will result in "OverflowError: long int too large to convert to int"
2. It doesn't seem to work:

   ```
   a = open("blah.txt", "w", 2 ** 31 - 1)
   for i in xrange(10000): 
       a.write("a")
   ```

Open up the file without closing python, and you will see the text

Answer (score 3):

You can open your file with as large a buffer as you want.  For example, to use up to a billion bytes for buffering, `x=open('/tmp/za', 'w', 1000*1000*1000)` -- if you have a hundred billion bytes of memory and want to use them all, just add another *100...;-).  Memory will only be consumed in the amount actually needed, so, no worry...

Answer (score 1):

I would say this partly depends on what you're trying to do.

The case where I came across this issue was when my application was a bit slow 
creating a file that was used by another application, the other application 
would get incomplete versions of the file.

I solved it by writing the file to a different place, then renaming it into the correct
place once I'd finished writing.

If you want this for other reasons then maybe that doesn't help.

Comment: This is worth testing. Writing the file locally and using the OS to copy it to the network might be faster. thanks